# Translating void* from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, void-pointers

I was translating some managed c++ code to c# and I came across a structure member of type void*.
Now, 2 objects of that struct is created, one whose void* member accepts a string and another case accepting address of an int variable.

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE        findTemplate;
findTemplate->pValue = sUserName;
```

In another case,

```
int x = 3;
CK_ATTRIBUTE        findTemplate;
findTemplate->pValue = &x;
```

How would I translate this void* member in c#? Has it something to do with IntPtr?

Comment: How does a `void*` "accept" a string?

Comment: What do you mean by translate?  If you're using interop then you would use an IntPtr but if you are just trying to recreate what it does in pure C# then you probably just want to use standard reference types.

Comment: @JohnDibling The object at the memory location referred to by that pointer is the start of a `string` object.

Comment: If you're not using interop then you probably want to just use a standard `object` type instead of IntPtr.  An object field can hold a reference to any reference type so it's probably the closest thing to a void pointer.

Comment: @TrevorElliott I prefer using pure c#. sso what would be the standard reference types?

Comment: a null terminated char array

Comment: Check the code and see if there's a reason for it having a pointer to the int instead of just passing the int directly. If there isn't, just make it an int, if there is, let us know what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ a void pointer can point to anything.  It says to the compiler, "Don't check the type of this."  The closest translation in c# is Object.

Comment: @TylerDurden.  Yes.  So an int will be boxed, but a String is already a ref.

Comment: So, if void* was a function parameter rather than a struct member and if I translated that as an object type. Will int be passed as a reference type without writing ref or out?